# Frustrated Animation Issue

Tags: apache-flex, animation, state, transition

I have spent 2 hours on this simple state to state transition with simply resize and move animation.... I can get the element to move and fade...but there is no resize animation at all. The panel element stay the same width whole time. If I copy the code to a brand new test mxml file, it works, but not in my main application file...I was wondering if someone here can help me out. Thanks a lot.

```
//This is a custom component inside the main application...Not sure if it relates to my issue.....

<mx:Canvas xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" width="1000" height="600" xmlns:getcomplist="services.getcomplist.*" xmlns:components="components.*"
currentState="defaultState">

<fx:Script>
<![CDATA[

   protected function compList_changeHandler(event:IndexChangeEvent):void
   {
       currentState="whenClick";
   }

]]>
</fx:Script>

<mx:states>
<s:State name="defaultState"/>
<s:State name="whenClick" />
</mx:states>

<mx:transitions>
<s:Transition toState="whenClick">

<s:Parallel target="{animationIsAnnoying}">
<!--<s:Fade duration="1000"/>-->    // Fade is working fine...
<s:Resize heightFrom="600" duration="5000" />  //resize is not working
<s:Move xFrom="500" duration="5000" />  //Move is working fine
</s:Parallel>

</s:Transition>
</mx:transitions>


<s:HGroup>

<s:List id="compList"
width="280"
height="500"
change="compList_changeHandler(event)">
</s:List>


<s:Panel id="animationIsAnnoying" height="150" includeIn="whenClick" /> //The panel I want to animated...


<components:compDisplayDetail includeIn="whenClick" id="compDisplay" width="600" height="500" userPic="{userPicResult.lastResult}" dataFromClick ="{compDetailinfoResult.lastResult}" /> 

</s:HGroup>


</mx:Canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

You must have a click event to command the resize component

im using here mx:Resize component

```
<mx:Resize id="resizeThis" target="{toolBoxContainer}"/>
<mx:VBox id="toolBoxContainer" height="200" width="300" >           
                <mx:Textid="txt" text="HELLO"/>
        </mx:VBox>

<mx:Button id="menuImage"toolTip="Show/Hidden Menu" click="menuClickHandler(event)" toggle="true"/> 

<mx:Script>
<![CDATA[
private var toggle:int =1;
private function menuClickHandler(e:MouseEvent):void {

                if(toggle == 0 ) { 

                    //MoveThis.end();
                    resizeThis.widthFrom = 0
                    resizeThis.widthTo = 46; 
                    resizeThis.play();

                }
                if(toggle == 1) {

                    resizeThis.end();
                    resizeThis.widthFrom = 46
                    resizeThis.widthTo = 0; 
                    resizeThis.play();
                }

                if(toggle == 0) toggle = 1;
                else toggle = 0;

            }
    ]]>
    </mx:Script>
```

This thing has errors in imports or the likes.. but i assume you got my point..

Comment: I do..My List change event should be equal to the click. Since I use state transition, I believe if the state changes, the animation should fire.... I even tried other effect like zoom. They don't work well either. The entire animation for Transition is mess up..:( and I think its Flex's or FPlayer issue.Thanks though..+1..

Comment: well try having it in a button where you fire the animation. then if it works.. then maybe assigning the state does not cover the resizing animation.